# combine polygons retain width

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal

I'd like to combine polygons if the length is less than say 6000 feet. I've attached an example of an area that I'd like to combine. I'd like to do this with a script as I have thousands of polygons to go through. Any help is much appreciated!

Source data:

```
structure(list(OBJECTID = c(18, 85, 130, 171, 173, 195, 212, 
255, 278, 295, 398, 402, 404, 410, 414, 608, 611, 616, 620, 622, 
191535, 191596, 191643, 191679), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(
    structure(c(790772.665095329, 795904.962015067, 795472.274595637, 
    794819.684650924, 789702.337778083, 790772.665095329, 55111.376137689, 
    54042.8837942318, 52039.046812771, 48862.3220103642, 49927.461344996, 
    55111.376137689), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(796612.78343804, 795904.962015067, 
790772.665095329, 791304.482601099, 791579.937704929, 791852.041080199, 
796999.435683555, 796612.78343804, 57336.4489387319, 54042.8837942318, 
55111.376137689, 57716.054447086, 58991.1885930025, 60295.399870716, 
59201.7374421435, 57336.4489387319), .Dim = c(8L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(797734.154390534, 
797201.624709836, 796999.435683555, 791852.041080199, 792383.947950958, 
792912.660267584, 795484.332670061, 798093.692520351, 797734.154390534, 
62633.767892387, 60203.5702778084, 59201.7374421435, 60295.399870716, 
62863.7415608288, 65428.4236166867, 64890.6613532156, 64342.4628359582, 
62633.767892387), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(795484.332670061, 792912.660267584, 
793994.470344538, 799177.835454204, 798842.652002334, 798093.692520351, 
795484.332670061, 64890.6613532156, 65428.4236166867, 70612.5829219612, 
69534.0760361488, 67931.049719191, 64342.4628359582, 64890.6613532156
), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(794819.684650924, 799636.528996167, 799981.263539694, 
    799763.980295563, 799625.316078716, 798915.162525192, 793752.758832907, 
    794819.684650924, 48862.3220103642, 47857.532466591, 47787.3435792962, 
    46712.6490712543, 46002.2938342407, 42603.1707699664, 43692.8731840489, 
    48862.3220103642), .Dim = c(8L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(799636.528996167, 794819.684650924, 
795472.274595637, 799601.503665015, 799636.528996167, 47857.532466591, 
48862.3220103642, 52039.046812771, 52138.699895762, 47857.532466591
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(799601.503665015, 795472.274595637, 795904.962015067, 
    796612.78343804, 799559.038835281, 799601.503665015, 52138.699895762, 
    52039.046812771, 54042.8837942318, 57336.4489387319, 57416.4914524728, 
    52138.699895762), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(797734.154390534, 799504.161914641, 
799519.096766394, 799523.689747001, 799559.038835281, 796612.78343804, 
796999.435683555, 797201.624709836, 797734.154390534, 62633.767892387, 
62679.6580485063, 60257.1450638027, 60060.7433085733, 57416.4914524728, 
57336.4489387319, 59201.7374421435, 60203.5702778084, 62633.767892387
), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(798667.422087686, 798915.162525192, 799625.316078716, 
    799675.110751155, 798667.422087686, 41404.585298834, 42603.1707699664, 
    46002.2938342407, 41415.711561777, 41404.585298834), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(797734.154390534, 798093.692520351, 798842.652002334, 
    799477.407371662, 799500.099509694, 799504.161914641, 797734.154390534, 
    62633.767892387, 64342.4628359582, 67931.049719191, 67943.0558978718, 
    65320.5209551165, 62679.6580485063, 62633.767892387), .Dim = c(7L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(799625.316078716, 799763.980295563, 802088.724803159, 
    802223.263591026, 804882.877008304, 804922.838745296, 802128.435622406, 
    799675.110751155, 799625.316078716, 46002.2938342407, 46712.6490712543, 
    46750.6814760173, 46752.8926281596, 46787.5460917902, 41527.9361136832, 
    41468.0690686702, 41415.711561777, 46002.2938342407), .Dim = c(9L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(799636.528996167, 799601.503665015, 802047.960395525, 
    802119.914713131, 804823.025000485, 804882.877008304, 802223.263591026, 
    802088.724803159, 799763.980295563, 799981.263539694, 799636.528996167, 
    47857.532466591, 52138.699895762, 52171.1430120492, 52172.0902911819, 
    52192.5345130677, 46787.5460917902, 46752.8926281596, 46750.6814760173, 
    46712.6490712543, 47787.3435792962, 47857.532466591), .Dim = c(11L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(802114.494253742, 804813.536856739, 804823.025000485, 
    802119.914713131, 802047.960395525, 799601.503665015, 799559.038835281, 
    802008.148001249, 802114.494253742, 57464.7329639106, 57554.278370772, 
    52192.5345130677, 52172.0902911819, 52171.1430120492, 52138.699895762, 
    57416.4914524728, 57462.7230153075, 57464.7329639106), .Dim = c(9L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(802114.494253742, 802008.148001249, 799559.038835281, 
    799523.689747001, 799519.096766394, 799504.161914641, 801968.3458121, 
    804782.760205713, 804787.182601505, 804813.536856739, 802114.494253742, 
    57464.7329639106, 57462.7230153075, 57416.4914524728, 60060.7433085733, 
    60257.1450638027, 62679.6580485063, 62750.767555581, 62832.1968387173, 
    60194.9664029238, 57554.278370772, 57464.7329639106), .Dim = c(11L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(804739.496925173, 804761.88531762, 804762.773230746, 
    804769.592161392, 804782.760205713, 801968.3458121, 799504.161914641, 
    799500.099509694, 799477.407371662, 801928.73953879, 802019.409522007, 
    804739.496925173, 68106.3930222505, 66807.9401796348, 65458.3953441062, 
    64152.5487757422, 62832.1968387173, 62750.767555581, 62679.6580485063, 
    65320.5209551165, 67943.0558978718, 68010.5408628952, 68013.0434007888, 
    68106.3930222505), .Dim = c(12L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(804922.838745296, 804882.877008304, 
810114.14861501, 810145.907565417, 804922.838745296, 41527.9361136832, 
46787.5460917902, 46900.4548796072, 41589.8156082104, 41527.9361136832
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(810110.073021085, 810118.538415086, 810114.14861501, 
    804882.877008304, 804823.025000485, 810110.073021085, 52269.5158709572, 
    49563.208246226, 46900.4548796072, 46787.5460917902, 52192.5345130677, 
    52269.5158709572), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(810110.073021085, 804823.025000485, 
804813.536856739, 807434.479329642, 810089.844191036, 810110.073021085, 
52269.5158709572, 52192.5345130677, 57554.278370772, 57628.8701270838, 
57700.2990023741, 52269.5158709572), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(804813.536856739, 
804787.182601505, 804782.760205713, 807390.853225214, 810055.199132969, 
810061.919256549, 810089.844191036, 807434.479329642, 804813.536856739, 
57554.278370772, 60194.9664029238, 62832.1968387173, 62899.4318649497, 
62970.9290954731, 60493.7685195097, 57700.2990023741, 57628.8701270838, 
57554.278370772), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(804739.496925173, 807375.326414109, 
810020.487459965, 810055.199132969, 807390.853225214, 804782.760205713, 
804769.592161392, 804762.773230746, 804761.88531762, 804739.496925173, 
68106.3930222505, 68173.8400793809, 68248.8573495335, 62970.9290954731, 
62899.4318649497, 62832.1968387173, 64152.5487757422, 65458.3953441062, 
66807.9401796348, 68106.3930222505), .Dim = c(10L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(790772.665095329, 
789702.337778083, 787092.050596808, 784500.54150305, 785549.734241135, 
786884.535917274, 790772.665095329, 55111.376137689, 49927.461344996, 
50476.317793333, 51036.4057055915, 56216.3557296265, 55916.5970048284, 
55111.376137689), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(789226.847106716, 791852.041080199, 
791579.937704929, 791304.482601099, 790772.665095329, 786884.535917274, 
785549.734241135, 786629.889714253, 787954.997612727, 789226.847106716, 
60843.9708908502, 60295.399870716, 58991.1885930025, 57716.054447086, 
55111.376137689, 55916.5970048284, 56216.3557296265, 61392.938091041, 
61111.3484171478, 60843.9708908502), .Dim = c(10L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
"POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(789226.847106716, 
787954.997612727, 786629.889714253, 787159.189681444, 787716.264357803, 
792912.660267584, 792383.947950958, 791852.041080199, 789226.847106716, 
60843.9708908502, 61111.3484171478, 61392.938091041, 63939.3317737952, 
66525.9576669169, 65428.4236166867, 62863.7415608288, 60295.399870716, 
60843.9708908502), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(788606.470246906, 789702.337778083, 
794819.684650924, 793752.758832907, 788606.470246906, 44765.2468782581, 
49927.461344996, 48862.3220103642, 43692.8731840489, 44765.2468782581
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    input = "+init=epsg:2257", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / New Mexico East (ftUS)\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4269]],\n    CONVERSION[\"SPCS83 New Mexico East zone (US Survey feet)\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",31,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-104.333333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.999909091,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",541337.5,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",15339]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"USA - New Mexico - SPCS - E\"],\n        BBOX[32,-105.72,37,-102.99]]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 784500.54150305, 
ymin = 41404.585298834, xmax = 810145.907565417, ymax = 70612.5829219612
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 24L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is an image that I'm trying to achieve with the red boxes. The grey data are the original outlines.
[image]
thanks,

Update: The code works great below if the polygons are facing north/south.  However when polygons are angles I believe the centroids will not work as a filter and grouping function.

```
polygon_corrds<- st_centroid(polygon)
polygon_corrds<- st_coordinates(polygon_corrds)%>%as_tibble()

polygon<- polygon%>%mutate(RowID=row_number())
polygon_corrds<- polygon_corrds%>%mutate(RowID=row_number())

polygon<- left_join(polygon,polygon_corrds)

polygon<-polygon%>%ungroup()%>%arrange(X,Y)%>%mutate(RowID2=row_number())


polygon<- polygon%>%mutate(RowID3= ifelse( RowID %%2==0,RowID,RowID2+1))



polygonx=polygon %>% 
  group_by(RowID3) %>%
  summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(polygonx) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill=as.factor(RowID3)))+theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the st_snap_to_grid might be what I need.

Comment: That didn't work. Is there a way to sort the polygons and add a mutated column? I've tried using the centroids but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by length? Perimeter? Length across the long dimension?

Comment: Yes, length across the long dimension if possible.

Comment: Is there a way to find the minimum rectangle of each polygon. Here is an answer but it is written in python.https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/finding-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points/169633#169633